# Using socket.io with pure websocket on client

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, websocket, socket.io

We have the node.js serverside and angular 6 web-application. I'm using socket.io/socket.io-client and it works fine.
 
 But now we must handle requests from an android application that is being developed by another company. This mobile app can't connect to socket.io because it makes use of "its own websockets".
 
 Can I configurate my socket.io so as to make it able to connect the mobile app to socket.io by pure ws transport?